# Error comparing two fields

Tags: java, android, json, db4o

I want to compare objects from db4o and JSON.I should delete the object in db4o if this doesn't exist in JSON.

I've a problem with the if:

```
if(tratdb4o.getMedication()==tratJson.getMedication()
```

I Log the two String variables and both are identical but doesn't enter into the If for change the value of igual.

Somebody knows why?

```
for (int i=0;it2.hasNext();i++ ) {
    objetoDb4o=it2.next();
    tratdb4o=(Tratam)objetoDb4o;
    for (int j=0;it.hasNext();j++ ) {
        objetoJson = it.next();
        tratJson = (Tratam)objetoJson;
        Log.d(TAG,"Comparing "+tratdb4o.getMedication()+" of db4o  "+ tratJson.getMedication() +" of JSON");

        if(tratdb4o.getMedication()==tratJson.getMedication()
             igual true;
        }

        if (igual==false){
            db4oHelper.db().delete(tratdb4o);
            db4oHelper.listResult();    
        }
        igual=false;
        it=listaendb4o.iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
tratdb4o.getMedication()==tratJson.getMedication()
```

do

```
tratdb4o.getMedication().equals(tratJson.getMedication())
```

Comment: or possibly `equalsIgnoreCase` if you don't care about capital letters

Answer (score 1):

for string you dont use "== "

```
    tratdb4o.getMedication().equals(tratJson.getMedication());
```

but for checking notequals you can still use !=